# How to change the language of Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition Beta?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Title says it all. Windows is non-English, but I want to play *Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition Beta* in English.

Comment: Isn't there a language button on the title screen, just like in regular minecraft? It should be in the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a button on main screen.

[image: Button on main page]
[image: That menu]

Comment: Seriously, that looks like it opens a web page …

Comment: @Daniel https://twitter.com/ardaozkal/status/632983215276470272

Answer (score 2):

I was asking this question in 2020 because there is no world icon main screen now.

It is located under the settings or whatever it is in your languages.
In that picture it is ayarlar as in Turkish language.
Click it and find languages.

Edit: Question turned into an answer.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the language can be changed in the Settings at the vey end.