# Changing the language of Minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My twins both have Minecraft PE on the Hudl2. One of them has changed the language to German.

How do I change it back?

Comment: Does it have a button like this? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232031/how-to-change-the-language-of-minecraft-windows-10-edition-beta/232037#232037

Answer (score 2):

On the main screen, find the globe icon.

Clicking on it will lead to a list of languages.

[image]

Locate and click on "English."